# Form in Bootstrap goes wrong

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my code:

```
 <div class="col-lg-2"> </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">Keterangan Badan</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Tinggi Badan</label> 
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tinggi_badan" id="tinggi_badan" placeholder="Tinggi Badan">
                </div><br><br> 

              <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Berat Badan</label> 
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="berat_badan" id="berat_badan" placeholder="Berat Badan">
                </div><br><br> 

              <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Jenis Rambut</label> 
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alamat" id="alamat" placeholder="Jenis Rambut">
                </div><br><br> 

              <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Bentuk Wajah</label> 
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alamat" id="alamat" placeholder="Bentuk Wajah">
                </div><br><br> 

              <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Warna Kulit</label> 
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="warna_kulit" id="warna_kulit" placeholder="Warna Kulit">
                </div><br><br> 
          </div>  
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">Keterangan Lainnya</div>
          <div class="panel-body">

          </div>  
      </div> 
    </div>
```

But the result is:

[image]

And then the other sides had some problems too.

Here's the code:

```
<label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Tempat Lahir</label> 
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ttl_propinsi" id="ttl_propinsi" placeholder="ttl_propinsi">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ttl_kota" id="ttl_kota" placeholder="ttl_kota">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ttl_tempat" id="ttl_tempat" placeholder="ttl_tempat">
  </div><br><br>

  <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Tanggal Lahir</label> 
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tanggal lahir" id="tanggal lahir" placeholder="Tanggal Lahir">
  </div>

  <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Jenis Kelamin</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4"form-co>
    <select name="jenis_kelamin" class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Gol Darah</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4"form-co>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gol_darah" id="gol_darah" placeholder="Gol Darah">
  </div>
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Should I make some CSS there?

Comment: Good thing you fixed your `s` key before typing `css`. dont' think I could stand a 5 mile long cssssss.... this late on a friday.

Comment: "should i make some css there ??? thankyou"  I think you should make some more s and ? characters. sorry I couldn't resist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your design is that your labels are not able adjust within their designated space. I'll advice increasing the label's grid size to 3 and decreasing input box's grid size to 9. 
Please refer code.

```
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Tinggi Badan</label> 
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tinggi_badan" id="tinggi_badan" placeholder="Tinggi Badan">
            </div>
```

The other problem simply requires you to add margin.

```
<style>
.form-control.mb10
{
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
</style>
```

Now add the class mb10 to your form controls.

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb10" name="ttl_propinsi" id="ttl_propinsi" placeholder="ttl_propinsi">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb10" name="ttl_kota" id="ttl_kota" placeholder="ttl_kota">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb10" name="ttl_tempat" id="ttl_tempat" placeholder="ttl_tempat">
</div>
```